# How to use Jade with Hapi framework

Tags: node.js, pug, hapi.js

*How can I use Jade with Hapi Framework?*

Specially, How to send the data with a Jade form and a Hapi function.

Thanks

Comment: Can we get this question opened up again? It was edited and hasn't been "off topic" since March 11, 2015.

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at the Hapi tutorials?  There's one specifically for views: http://hapijs.com/tutorials/views.  Furthermore, there's an example made for Jade here: https://github.com/spumko/hapi/blob/master/examples/views/jade/index.js

So from the documentation, you would configure your server similarly to this:

```
var options = {
    views: {
        engines: { jade: require('jade') },
        path: __dirname + '/templates',
        compileOptions: {
            pretty: true
        }
    }
};
```

Then when rendering the view, you can pass data to the template like so:

```
reply.view('index', {
    title: 'examples/views/jade/index.js | Hapi ' + Hapi.version,
    message: 'Index - Hello World!'
});
```

There's also another great tutorial on Hapi which has a part on views: https://github.com/spumko/makemehapi

Hope that helps